# C# Extension methods on "members"

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

I have some extension methods which could be used like this:

```
MyType myObject; 
string displayName = myObject.GetDisplayName(x => x.Property);
```

The problem here is that it needs an instance, even if the extension method only needs the type `MyType`. So if there is no instance, it needs to be called like this:

```
string displayName = BlahBlahUtility.GetDisplayName((MyTpe x) => x.Property);
```

Which is not so nice anymore.

**Is there a way to write better syntax for such cases?**

What I actually want to do is this (pseudo language):

```
string displayName = MyType.Property.GetDisplayName()
```

Which of course does not work with C#.

But what about something like this:

```
string displayName = ((MyType x) => x.Property).GetDisplayName();
```

This is also not possible (after a lambda, a dot is not accepted).

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**:

My "favorite syntax" `MyType.Property.GetDisplayName()` seems to be misleading. I don't talk about static properties here. I know that this syntax won't be possible. I just tried to show in pseudo language, what information is necessary. This would be ideal, every additional stuff is just syntactical overhead. Any working syntax that is close to this would be great.

I don't want to write a certain extension method. I want an easy, readable and compile time safe syntax, **using any language feature**.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's static reflection over member names in a type

Comment: You can't make static extension methods in C#3. If it's your own type you're extending, why can't you add this method directly?

Comment: @Quick: An extension method like "GetDisplayName" works on any member of any class. @saret: huh? @Bruno: I want an easy and compile time safe syntax to get information about members, like the display name.

Comment: I think I got misunderstood. I don't want to write a certain extension method. I want an easy, readable and compile time safe **syntax**, using any language feature.

Comment: "Property" has to be a static member.  Why are you using a lambda?

Comment: @nobugz: no, Property is not static, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: What do you mean by "display name"? Is it how the name of that property should be displayed?

Comment: @ Stefan Steinegger I assumed you're using the extension method to do "reflection" on the name of the property you're referencing so you get back a string representation of the Propertie's Name

Comment: @saret: Yes, the extension method could use reflection. But it is compile time type safe and very easy to read.

Comment: @Stefan - I put reflection in quotes as this technique isn't using the reflection apis, it just takes the Expression created and uses that to get the string name of the property

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're trying to do. You're looking for a syntax to do what? What is this "display name" you're talking about?

Comment: @Bruno, @John: DisplayName is a localized name of the property. It could be any static information about the property. For instance a value of a certain attribute. I just thought DisplayName is the easiest to understand.

Comment: "For instance" the value of a certain attribute, or "only" the value of an attribute? Do you always want to get an attribute that's applied to a member (property)?

Comment: Theres something I'm missing from your description, in order to be able to call `myObject.GetDisplayName(x => x.Property)`, wouldn't you need an extension with a signature similar to :
`public static string GetDisplayName(this MyType o, Func<MyType, Property> myFunc)`
Or, with generics
`public static string GetDisplayName<T,U>(this T o, Func<T, U> myFunc)`
If thats the case, wouldn't your call to `BlahBlahUtility.GetDisplayName((MyTpe x) => x.Property);` actually be `BlahBlahUtility.GetDisplayName(x, _ => _.Property);` ?

Comment: @Dynami Le-Savard: The method is just declared as `GetDisplayName<T,U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> memberExpression)` and called as `GetDisplayName((MyType x) => x.Property)`. I don't need to pass an instance of MyType.

Comment: @John Saunders: Currently, the information is provided by attributes. But it could be any data related to the member. (Resources, NHibernate mapping meta-data, other configuration, really anything you can think of). The challenge is that the member specification (the lambda here) is the argument, and the functionality should be very easy to use, as with extension methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `Express` and `Reflect` classes in the [Lokad Shared Libraries](http://abdullin.com/shared-libraries/). Think they may help out with what you are trying to do. Read more here:

- [Strongly Typed Reflection in Lokad Shared](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/1/3/strongly-typed-reflection-in-lokad-shared.html)
- [How to Find Out Variable or Parameter Name in C#?](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I'll probably find something there.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment: "I want an easy and compile time safe syntax to get information about members".

This is a very frequently requested feature and has been discussed in the C# team's meetings for about a decade, but has never been prioritised high enough to be included.

This blog post explains why:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx

So for now, you're just going to be fighting against a missing feature. Maybe you could post more information about your broader problem and see if people can suggest different approaches.

**Update**

Without more info about your problem this is just guesswork. But if you have a property that represents a value but also carries additional "meta" information, you could always represent that as a new type and use an "injection" step to set everything up.

Here's a suggested abstract interface to such a "meta property":

```
public interface IMetaProperty<TValue>
{
    TValue Value { get; set; }

    string DisplayName { get; }

    event Action<TValue, TValue> ValueChanged;
}
```

The value of the property is just another sub-property, with its type defined by the user.

I've put in the display name, and also as a bonus you've got an event that fires when the value changes (so you get "observability" for free).

To have properties like this in a class, you'd declare it like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IMetaProperty<string> FirstName { get; private set; }
    public IMetaProperty<string> LastName { get; private set; }
    public IMetaProperty<int> Age { get; private set; }

    public SomeClass() { MetaProperty.Inject(this); }
}
```

Note how the setters on the properties are private. This stops anyone from accidentally setting the property itself instead of setting the Value sub-property.

So this means the class has to set up those properties so they aren't just `null`. It does this by calling a magic `Inject` method, which can work on any class:

```
public static class MetaProperty
{
    // Make it convenient for us to fill in the meta information
    private interface IMetaPropertyInit
    {
        string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    // Implementation of a meta-property
    private class MetaPropertyImpl<TValue> : IMetaProperty<TValue>, 
                                             IMetaPropertyInit
    {
        private TValue _value;

        public TValue Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                var old = _value;
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged(old, _value);
            }
        }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public event Action<TValue, TValue> ValueChanged = delegate { };
    }

    public static void Inject(object target)
    {
        // for each meta property...
        foreach (var property in target.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                        p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
                            == typeof(IMetaProperty<>)))
        {
            // construct an implementation with the correct type
            var impl = (IMetaPropertyInit) 
                typeof (MetaPropertyImpl<>).MakeGenericType(
                    property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()
                ).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

            // initialize any meta info (could examine attributes...)
            impl.DisplayName = property.Name;

            // set the value
            property.SetValue(target, impl, null);
        }
    }
}
```

It just uses reflection to find all the `IMetaProperty` slots hiding in the object, and fills them in with an implementation.

So now a user of `SomeClass` could say:

```
var sc = new SomeClass
             {
                 FirstName = { Value = "Homer" },
                 LastName = { Value = "Simpson" },
                 Age = { Value = 38 },
             };

Console.WriteLine(sc.FirstName.DisplayName + " = " + sc.FirstName.Value);

sc.Age.ValueChanged += (from, to) => 
    Console.WriteLine("Age changed from " + from + " to " + to);

sc.Age.Value = 39;

// sc.Age = null; compiler would stop this
```

If you're already using an IOC container you may be able to achieve some of this without going directly to reflection.

Comment: Isn't there any better idea then calling the static method normally?

Comment: There might be, if you post more information about your broader problem. e.g. depending on the scale of what you're doing, code generation may help, or it might be overkill.

Comment: Updated with a different idea.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. Because it must work on any class, it must not be intrusive. The meta-information that is returned by the expression is already there, somewhere, for instance in an attribute or somewhere else, it doesn't matter. I just want to exchange the call to my ugly static method (`BlahBlahUtility.GetDisplayName`) to something more readable.

Comment: You already know you can't "just" do that. :) What I can't understand is why you need this facility. What is the use case? In what situation is someone going to be hand-writing code that gets the display name associated with a property?

Comment: The display name is taken from a resource by naming convention. (This is also done by an attribute, only for data binding in the UI). Another use case is the ReflectionUtility.GetMemberName, which returns the name of the member in the expression. It really doesn't matter what it does and where the information comes from, there is something common: the argument is a lambda expression which specifies a member. The method needs to be implemented on a central place, it doesn't belong to a certain class, a typical case for an extension method. But this doesn't work here.

Comment: If this is for generating a UI that is bound to the properties, why does it need to be hand-coded? Why not use reflection on the object to automatically generate the UI by looping through the properties and creating suitable controls for them?

Comment: I don't want to use it for the UI. I need it for reporting, logging, error messages etc. etc. in the server. And there are static properties which should be localized the same way. Reflection is much to long, unreadable, error prone. The method to get it is already there, it is simple, but shouldn't be implemented every time when a display name is needed. Getting display names should be trivial. And - again, this is everything specific to display names. There are other syntactically similar cases where I don't like the syntax.

Comment: But my point is the same: you have a variety of classes with properties. And you want to report, log, generate error messages. You seem to be saying that someone will have to hand-write the code to format an error message that includes the display names and values of properties in the object, or something like that. Why? You can write a single function that takes any object and turns it into an error message, all controlled by attributes on the properties. There is no need to write it by hand in each case, and hence no need for a short syntax to get PropertyInfo from a property identifier.

Comment: I already wrote a single method that returns the data related to a single member, so it is reusable for any case. This is my BlahBlahUtility. I'm happy with the functionality of it and don't want to change anything there. I just don't like that I need to call BlahBlahUtility. The data is related to the member, so it should be easily recoverable next to the member. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a static extension method?

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Yesterday(); // Static extension.
```

Instead of

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Yesterday(); // Extension on DateTime instance.
```

If this is what you're trying to pull off, I do not believe it is possible in the current version of C#.

Comment: I don't want a static extension method. I would like a easy syntax, using any language feature. I added a section to the question to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are integrating layers a little too tightly.  Normally in this type of situation I would let the presentation layer decide the implementation of `GetDisplayName()` instead of making it an extension of the property itself.  You could create an interface called `MyTypeDisplayer` or whatever you fancy, and let there be multiple implementations of it not limiting you to a single display implementation.

Comment: Nope, if `GetDisplayName` has an object that is the value of MyType.Property, then it doesn't have the PropertyInfo for that property. It only has the value of the property. So it cannot obtain custom attributes, for example.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with layers. DisplayName is just an example. For instance it could return data taken from attributes.

Comment: @Stefan, the point is that you are integrating the data and how the data is being used into one location.  If MyType is compiled and you know all the properties and attributes at design time, you can create another class which interprets that data in the way in which you are trying to use it.

Comment: @NickLarsen: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. I just want to make the syntax shorter then calling static methods. I mean, `BlahBlahHelperClass.GetDisplayName((myClass x) => x)` is currently the working solution, I just want to make it shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that one cannot get a reference to non-static methods via instance MyType.[Member]. These can only be seen through a reference to an instance of the type. You also cannot build an extension method on-top of a type declaration, only on an instance of a type - that is the extension method itself has to be defined using an instance of a type (this T x).

One can however define the expression like this to get a reference to static members:
((MyType x) => MyType.Property)

One could do something similar to *string displayName = ((MyType x) => x.Property).GetDisplayName();*
The first issue is guaranteeing that the compiler treats your (x=> x.Property) as an Expression rather than an action/func etc... 
To do this one might need to do this:

```
string displayName = ((Expression<Func<PropertyType>>)((MyType x) => x.Property).GetDisplayName();
```

The extension method would then have to be defined like this:

```
public static string GetDisplayName<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> expression)
```

You might also have to define an extension method on top of `Expression<Action>> and Expression<Action<T>>` if your members are also methods.

You can do a dot after an Expression - this is where the Compile method would reside.

Appended:

I think the static call to the extension method in cases that one doesn't have an instance of the type one needs to do "reflection" on to determine a Members name would be the cleanest syntax still - this way you could still use the extension method when using an instance of a type and fall back to the static call definition => `MyExtensionClass.GetDisplayName(TypeOfX x => TypeOfX.StaticMember OR  x.Property/Member)` when one doesn't have an instance

Comment: Yes, I already tried casting the lambda to the expression. But this is syntactically far from ideal, so I didn't even mention it. Then it's even better to call the static method directly.

Comment: I agree - also found having to put the explicit Expression definition in (can't use var expression = (t => t.Property); either as the compiler probably won't see it as an Expression, but just a Func<PropertyType> definition - so you would need var to become Expression<Func<PropertyType>>)

Unfortuanetly I'm not sure of a way to get the syntax to the clean state you'd like - also went the static extension method call route as it seemed cleaner...

MyExtensionClass.GetDisplayName(x => TypeOfX.StaticMember), but can still use the extension method if you have an instance of the type

Comment: Sorry i meant - I agree - also found having to put the explicit Expression definition in looks dirty syntax wise

Comment: I've edited my answer above - see the bottom for a bit more of an answer

Comment: You can create a helper method in the class you doing this that takes the Expression and will call the ExtensionMethodClass.GetDisplayName for you => GetDisplayName(Mytype x=> x.Member), public static string GetDisplayName(Expression){return ExtensionMethodClass.GetDisplayName(expression);}

Comment: Calling the static method is what I'm already doing (second snippet in the question). I wan't to avoid this syntactical overhead (eg. the classname where the static method is declared in). I can't and don't want to influence MyType. This could be any type. Otherwise it would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you interface your properties, you could make the extension on the interface instead:

```
namespace Linq1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyType o = new MyType();
            o.Property.GetDisplayName();
        }
    }

    public class MyType
    {
        public IDisplayableProperty Property { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDisplayableProperty 
    {
        string GetText();
    }

    public class MyProperty1 : IDisplayableProperty 
    {
        public string GetText() { return "MyProperty2"; }
    }

    public class MyProperty2 : IDisplayableProperty 
    {
        public string GetText() { return "MyProperty2"; }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetDisplayName(this IDisplayableProperty o)
        {
            return o.GetText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just rename the `GetText` method to be `GetDisplayName`, and forget about the extension method?

Comment: Hm, qutie right. I suppose I did that when thinking about the static entry point 'Extensions.GetDisplayName(o.Property)'

Comment: I can't and don't want to influence MyType. This could be any type. Otherwise it would be easy.